# Why won't my tkinter button go where it is supposed to?

Tags: python, tkinter

The button is the `^` one.

[image: Image here.]

It's supposed to be at the red highlighted place, but it won't go there - no matter where I tell it to go, it will always go there (unless I completely remove the `self.button.grid(row=x,column=y)`.

Here is my (entire) code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.a = ''
        self.math1 = 0
        self.math2 = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.operation = '+'
        self.show_answer()
        self.method = ''

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Q', fg='red', command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit_button.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.c_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.c_button['text'] = 'C'
        self.c_button.command = self.clear_all
        self.c_button.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=4)
        self.c_button.config(width=9, height=1)

        self.one_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.one_button['text'] = 1
        self.one_button['command'] = self.add_1_to_str
        self.one_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.two_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.two_button['text'] = 2
        self.two_button['command'] = self.add_2_to_str
        self.two_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.three_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.three_button['text'] = 3
        self.three_button['command'] = self.add_3_to_str
        self.three_button.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.four_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.four_button['text'] = 4
        self.four_button['command'] = self.add_4_to_str
        self.four_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.five_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.five_button['text'] = 5
        self.five_button['command'] = self.add_5_to_str
        self.five_button.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.six_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.six_button['text'] = 6
        self.six_button['command'] = self.add_6_to_str
        self.six_button.grid(row=3, column=3)

        self.seven_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.seven_button['text'] = 7
        self.seven_button['command'] = self.add_7_to_str
        self.seven_button.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.eight_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.eight_button['text'] = 8
        self.eight_button['command'] = self.add_8_to_str
        self.eight_button.grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.nine_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.nine_button['text'] = 9
        self.nine_button['command'] = self.add_9_to_str
        self.nine_button.grid(row=4, column=3)

        self.zero_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.zero_button['text'] = 0
        self.zero_button['command'] = self.add_0_to_str
        self.zero_button.grid(row=5, column=2)

        self.equal_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.equal_button['text'] = '='
        self.equal_button['command'] = self.equal
        self.equal_button.grid(row=5, column=3)

        self.plus_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.plus_button['text'] = '+'
        self.plus_button['command'] = self.plus
        self.plus_button.grid(row=2, column=4)

        self.subtract_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.subtract_button['text'] = '-'
        self.subtract_button['command'] = self.subtract
        self.subtract_button.grid(row=3, column=4)
        self.subtract_button.config(width=1, height=1)

        self.multiply_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.multiply_button['text'] = 'X'
        self.multiply_button['command'] = self.multiply
        self.multiply_button.grid(row=4, column=4)

        self.divide_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.divide_button['text'] = '/'
        self.divide_button['command'] = self.multiply
        self.divide_button.grid(row=5, column=4)
        self.divide_button.config(width=1, height=1)

        self.square_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.square_button['text'] = '²'
        self.square_button['command'] = self.square
        self.square_button.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.square_button.config(width=1, height=1)

        self.square_root_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.square_root_button['text'] = '²√'
        self.square_root_button['command'] = self.square_root
        self.square_root_button.grid(row=6, column=2)
        self.square_root_button.config(width=1, height=1)

        self.power_button = tk.Button()
        self.power_button['text'] = '^'
        self.power_button['command'] = self.power
        self.power_button.grid(row=6, column=3)

    def power(self):
        self.operation = '^'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = str(self.a)
        self.a = ''

    def square_root(self):
        self.operation = '2root'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = 0
        self.equal()
        self.show_answer()

    def square(self):
        self.operation = '^2'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = 0

    def show_answer(self):
        self.answer_box = tk.Button(self)
        self.answer_box['text'] = self.total
        self.answer_box.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
        self.answer_box.config(width=9, height=1)

    def plus(self):
        self.operation = '+'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = str(self.a)
        self.a = ''

    def subtract(self):
        self.operation = '-'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = str(self.a)
        self.a = ''

    def multiply(self):
        self.operation = '*'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = str(self.a)
        self.a = ''

    def divide(self):
        self.operation = '/'
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math1 = self.a
        self.a = str(self.a)
        self.a = ''

    def equal(self):
        self.a = int(self.a)
        self.math2 = self.a
        self.math1 = int(self.math1)
        self.math2 = int(self.math2)
        if self.operation == '+':
            self.total = self.math1 + self.math2
        elif self.operation == '-':
            self.total = self.math1 - self.math2
        elif self.operation == '*':
            self.total = self.math1 * self.math2
        elif self.operation == '/':
            self.total = self.math1 / self.math2
        elif self.operation == '^2':
            self.total = self.math1 * self.math1
        elif self.operation == '2root':
            self.total = math.sqrt(self.math1)
        elif self.operation == '^':
            self.total = 1
            for a in range(0, self.math2):
                self.total = self.total * self.math1

        self.math1 = str(self.math1)
        self.math2 = str(self.math2)
        self.total = str(self.total)
        if self.operation == '^2':
            print(self.math1 + 'X' + self.math1 + '=' + self.total)
        else:
            print(self.math1 + self.operation + self.math2 + '=' + self.total)
        self.math1 = 0
        self.math2 = 0
        self.a = '0'
        self.answer_box.destroy()
        self.show_answer()
        self.total = 0

    def add_1_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '1'

    def add_2_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '2'

    def add_3_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '3'

    def add_4_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '4'

    def add_5_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '5'

    def add_6_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '6'

    def add_7_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '7'

    def add_8_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '8'

    def add_9_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '9'

    def add_0_to_str(self):
        self.a = self.a + '0'

    def clear_all(self):
        self.a = '0'
        self.math1 = 0
        self.math2 = 0
        print(self.a)
        self.answer_box.destroy()
        self.total = 0
        self.show_answer()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to make it go to `self.button.grid(row=6, column=3)` correctly?

(edit) the math works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
self.power_button = tk.Button()
```

into

```
self.power_button = tk.Button(self)
```

Comment: If you stare at some code long enough, you just don't see things like that anymore. Then you know it is time to take a break.